# Adding multiple virtual switches to New-VM?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I'm working on a Powershell script to create new virtual machines as part of a migration between a Hyper-V server running Hyper-V Server 2012R2 and a new Hyper-V server running Hyper-V Server 2019.

For the virtual machines that have one single virtual switch assigned to them, this script works fine, however, I have some virtual machines that have two switches. For those VM's, I get this message: `Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter`.

How would I go about adding the second switch?

```
Import-Module -Name Hyper-V -RequiredVersion 1.1

$currentvms = Get-VM -ComputerName Hypervserver
foreach ($currentvm  in $currentvms)
{   
    $name = ($currentvm).Name
    $generation = ($currentvm).Generation
    $startupmemory = ($currentvm).MemoryStartup
    $virtualswitch = (Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $name -ComputerName Hypervserver).SwitchName 
    $virtualswitchcount = (Measure-Object -InputObject $virtualswitch).Count
    if ($virtualswitchcount -ne 1) 
    {
        New-VM -Name $name -Generation $generation -MemoryStartupBytes $startupmemory -SwitchName $virtualswitch[0],$virtualswitch[1] -ComputerName Hypervserver2 -WhatIf
    }
    else
     {
        New-VM -Name $name -Generation $generation -MemoryStartupBytes $startupmemory -SwitchName $virtualswitch -ComputerName Hypervserver2 -WhatIf
    }
    
}
```

Comment: IMHO stackoverflow.com would be a better fit for you

Comment: Are you saying that a VM exported from Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2012 R2 can't be imported to Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2019? If so, where did you read that?

Comment: It appears I may have misread that information.